# Comparing $a-\frac1b\sum_{x=1}^n(\log(-c_x)+\frac{d_x^2}{2c^2_x})$ and $a-\frac1b\sum_{x=1}^n(\log(-c_x)-\frac{d_x^2}{2c^2_x})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to figure out if $f$ is always smaller than $g$ but am having a hard time due to the summation operator. I have the following:

$$f = a - \frac{1}{b}\sum_{x = 1}^n\left(\log(-c_x)+\frac{d_x^2}{2c^2_x}\right)$$
and
$$g = a - \frac{1}{b}\sum_{x = 1}^n\left(\log(-c_x)-\frac{d_x^2}{2c^2_x}\right)$$

where $-\infty<a<\infty$, $b>0$, $c_x<0$, and $d_x>0$ $\forall x$.

Based empirically on plugging in values I believe it to be true but am having a hard time showing it (or finding a counter example).

A first attempt. If we let $n=1$ then $f-g$ simplifies to $-\frac{d^2}{bc^2}$ which is less than zero and so we must have that $f-g<0$. Now does this hold for $n>1$?

Comment: There are ways to algebraically rearrange expressions that have summation operators. Which of them are you familiar with?

Comment: @DavidK I'm not sure.

Comment: You can also often get clues from trying small numbers. If $n=1$ you can easily write the functions without summation operators. Can you solve the problem then? What if $n=2$?

Comment: @DavidK I see where you are going with this. For $n=1$ do I just need to solve $f(x) >g(x)$, rearrange terms and see if its true?

Comment: You can't have $x$ as the argument of $f$ and then a summation. I assume they are functions of the parameter $n$?

Comment: @T_M sorry yes.

Comment: One way I like to do this is imagine they are on either side of a symbol and you don't know whether or not that symbol is < or = or > . Now as long as you don't multiply both sides by (-1) you can still do simple things to both sides...can you do some 'cancelling' to end up working out whether it must have been < or >?

Comment: Another way is to write $f - g$ and then figure out whether it's positive, negative, or zero by substituting the formulas for $f$ and $g$ and then using algebra to simplify the result.

Comment: @T_M in the case of $n=1$, I get that $\frac{d^2}{2bc^2} > -\frac{d^2}{2bc^2}$ is that what you mean?

Comment: @DavidK I think that I have shown that $f-g<0$ for $n=1$ but is there an easy way to show it for the case of any $n$?

Comment: If $c>0$, how can you even write $\log(-c_x)$? It’s just undefined.

Comment: @insipidintegrator correct. I meant to have it as $c<0$ which has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first edit, $$f-g=-\frac1b\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{2d_x^2}{2c_x^2} =-\frac1b\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{d_x^2}{c_x^2}  $$ Now, $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^n\frac{d_x^2}{c_x^2}$ is a sum of perfect squares. Each term of the summation is strictly positive so the sum is also always positive (because you have mentioned that $d_x>0\ \forall x.$ The sum would equal zero iff each $d_x$ were equal to $0$).

Also, $b>0$ so $f-g<0$ so $f<g\ \forall n$.

---

Intuitively, you can think of it like: the summation part in $g$ is less than the summation in $f$ (because of the minus sign in it before the $\dfrac{d_x^2}{c_x^2}$ term) so a *smaller* quantity is getting subtracted from $a$ so the result is bigger in case of $g$.

Comment: Does this still hold now that I have made the correction that $c<0$?

Comment: The sign of $c$ is irrelevant to the problem as a whole, it is just needed for defining the log. So yeah, it holds.

Comment: The reason I ask is because isn't $\log(-c_x)$ a negative number between 0 and 1? Does this matter?

Comment: What do you mean “negative number between 0 and 1”? There are no negative numbers between 0 and 1

Comment: Sorry I mean isn't $\log(c_x) <0$ when $0<c_x<1$?

Comment: Yes it is. But that isn’t relevant. Subtracting something from a negative number still gives less than adding the same thing to that negative number. Eg. $-5-5=-10<-5+5=0$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just wanted to double check.